# simple_salesforce bulk insert - Duplicate Id error

Tags: api, insert, python, bulk, simple-salesforce

I am using the Python package **simple_salesforce** to bulk insert instances of a custom object. The custom object has *Account Id* as a foreign key, which I am inserting during the bulk insert.

I'm seeing an error in my bulk data load logs for *Duplicate Id*, which I have determined is referring to *Account Id*. I'm not sure why this would be flagged, since *Account Id* is not the primary key of the custom object. A support rep told me to look into my automation for this object. What specifically would case this issue?

Comment: Can anyone help me with this? Very stuck :/

Comment: Are you able to complete the same transaction through dataloader, data import wizard or the UI?